# Homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

This question was on my exam, and sadly I got it wrong.
I hope to amend for my failure by redoing the problem.
Can someone verify my reasoning? 
I would greatly appreciate.

Determine all homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$\mathbb{Z}$ has one generator as it is cyclic $\mathbb{Z} = \langle 1 \rangle$.
            We note that homomorphisms are completely determined by the value on the 
            generators. 
            Take $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $1 \mapsto r$ where $r \in \mathbb{R}$.
            There are infinitely many possible $r \in \mathbb{R}$.
            Hence there are infinitely many possible homomorphisms.

Comment: Yes, there are infinitely many homomorphisms, but the problem asks you to state what they are.

Comment: Can you just send 1 to any real number? @TimRaczkowski

Comment: Yes.  So suppose $\phi:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb R$ is a homomorphism with $\phi(1)=a$. So what is is $\phi(n)$?

Comment: $\phi(n)=\phi(1^n)=\phi(1)^n=a^n=na$. But is this what the problem is requiring? Can you just get by with the definition on the generator? @TimRaczkowski

Comment: I believe the problems is asking to you to explicitly give the homomorphism as you have just done.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you so much!